# conditionally hide or show a save button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make the below working without luck

I have one "session" text box
one "cost_per_session"
and the "total_cost"

I call the function "calculate()" to calculate the total cost and put it in the "total_cost"

I would like

if the "sessions" is blank

or if the total_cost is more than 50

the save button to be hidden

can someone help?

```html
<form method="post" action="#">
    <section>
        <label>Sessions: </label>
            <input type="text" name="sessions" id="sessions" autocomplete="off" placeholder="XX"
                oninput="
                    calculate();

                    if ($('#sessions').val() == '' || $('#total_cost').val() > 50)
                        {
                            $('#save_button_box').hide();
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            $('#save_button_box').show();
                        };
                " >
        </label>
    </section>

    <section>
        <label>Cost Per Session</label>
            <input type="text" name="cost_per_session" id="cost_per_session" readonly="" value="5">
        </label>
    </section>

    <section>
        <label class="label">Total Cost</label>
            <input type="text" name="total_cost" id="total_cost" readonly="">
        </label>
    </section>



    <div id="save_button_box" style="display:none;">
        <button type="submit" class="button">Save</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

```js
 function calculate() {
     var var_sessions = document.getElementById('sessions').value; 
     var var_cost_per_session = document.getElementById('cost_per_session').value;
 
     var result_total_cost = var_sessions * var_cost_per_session;
 
   
     total_cost.value = result_total_cost;
 
 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is what you want. Its your code I just moved the if from html to javascript and changed total_cost with result_total_cost

```js
function calculate() {
    var var_sessions = document.getElementById('sessions').value; 
    var var_cost_per_session = document.getElementById('cost_per_session').value;
    var result_total_cost = var_sessions * var_cost_per_session;

    var total_cost = document.getElementById('total_cost').value;
    console.log(var_sessions);
    console.log(total_cost);
    if (var_sessions == '' || result_total_cost > 50)
    {
      $('#save_button_box button').hide();
    }
    else
    {
      $('#save_button_box button').show();
    }
    document.getElementById('total_cost').value = result_total_cost;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="#">
    <section>
        <label>Sessions: </label>
            <input type="text" name="sessions" id="sessions" autocomplete="off" placeholder="XX" oninput="calculate();" >
        </label>
    </section>
    <section>
        <label>Cost Per Session</label>
            <input type="text" name="cost_per_session" id="cost_per_session" readonly="" value="5">
        </label>
    </section>
    <section>
        <label class="label">Total Cost</label>
            <input type="text" name="total_cost" id="total_cost" readonly="">
        </label>
    </section>
    <div id="save_button_box" style="">
        <button type="submit" class="button">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are doing everything good just 
arrange them well as I did...

```js
function calculate() {
    var var_sessions = document.getElementById('sessions').value;   
    var var_cost_per_session = document.getElementById('cost_per_session').value;

    var result_total_cost = var_sessions * var_cost_per_session;

    total_cost.value = result_total_cost;

    if ($('#sessions').val() == '' || $('#total_cost').val() > 50)
    {
        $('#save_button_box').hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#save_button_box').show();
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<form method="post" action="#">
    <section>
        <label>Sessions: </label>
            <input type="text" name="sessions" id="sessions" autocomplete="off" placeholder="XX" oninput="calculate();" >
        </label>
    </section>
    <section>
        <label>Cost Per Session</label>
            <input type="text" name="cost_per_session" id="cost_per_session" readonly="" value="5">
        </label>
    </section>
    <section>
        <label class="label">Total Cost</label>
            <input type="text" name="total_cost" id="total_cost" readonly="">
        </label>
    </section>
    <div id="save_button_box" style="display:none;">
        <button type="submit" class="button">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```